# comparing surf features between many images

Tags: comparison, surf

I am comparing many images based on surf features. I am able to compare only 2 images, but I need to do it for multiple images in two folders; can someone help me out?

```
functionname='OpenSurf.m';
functiondir=which(functionname);
functiondir=functiondir(1:end-length(functionname));
addpath([functiondir '/SubFunctions'])
defaultoptions=struct('tresh',0.0002,'octaves',5,'init_sample',2,'upright',false,'extended',false,'verbose',false);
if(~exist('Options','var')), 
    Options=defaultoptions; 
else
    tags = fieldnames(defaultoptions);
    for i=1:length(tags)
         if(~isfield(Options,tags{i})),  Options.(tags{i})=defaultoptions.(tags{i}); end
    end
    if(length(tags)~=length(fieldnames(Options))), 
        warning('register_volumes:unknownoption','unknown options found');
    end
end
iimg=IntegralImage_IntegralImage(img);
FastHessianData.thresh = Options.tresh;
FastHessianData.octaves = Options.octaves;
FastHessianData.init_sample = Options.init_sample;
FastHessianData.img = iimg;
ipts = FastHessian_getIpoints(FastHessianData,Options.verbose);
if(~isempty(ipts))
ipts = SurfDescriptor_DecribeInterestPoints(ipts,Options.upright, Options.extended, iimg, Options.verbose);
end
```

Comment: How are you comparing the images? Are you using some kind of matching-function?

Comment: Matching based on SIFT operator

Comment: If you know how to compare two images, comparing multiple images should just be a case of iterating through both folders and comparing each image of folder 1 with each image of folder 2. Or am I missing something?